# Trying to modularize methods for average, min and max

Tags: java

This is from a project that I recently submitted, and I'm kind of frustrated that I couldn't figure this out.

I've got an ArrayList of my objects called studentList; the Student objects' state consists of the following:

```
private String studentName;
private double quiz1;
private double quiz2;
private double quiz3;
private double quiz4;
private double midTermOne;
private double midTermTwo;
private double finalTest;
private String letterGrade;
```

I couldn't figure out how to modularize the following code in order to prevent repeating it for each column (i.e. test scores for a student):

```
...
double quiz1Total = 0.0;
double quiz1Avg = 0.0;
double quiz1min = studentsList.get(0).getQuiz1();
double quiz1max = studentsList.get(0).getQuiz1();

for (int i = 0; i < studentsList.size(); i++) {
    quiz1Total += studentsList.get(i).getQuiz1();
    if (studentsList.get(i).getQuiz1() > quiz1max) {
        quiz1max = studentsList.get(i).getQuiz1();
    } // if

    if (studentsList.get(i).getQuiz1() < quiz1min){
        quiz1min = studentsList.get(i).getQuiz1();
    } // if
} // for

quiz1Avg = quiz1Total / studentsList.size();
...
```

Is the recommendation to extract the test scores into a temp array first and then just pass that to the average/min/max method?

I'm not having trouble with the average/min/max concepts, just the model that I should be using so that I can modularize it.

Thanks.

Comment: How are quizzes identified? Eg do they have name or numeric id? Let me know

Comment: Do you have java8 available (since exactly that's what its bee "made for" :) ?

Comment: @xerx I see you have a translator getting in the way: "api" does translate to "bee", but I think you meant "API" :)

Comment: no, @Bohemian, just my "f" stuck -> beef made for :-)

Comment: average/min/max is easy, more fun is variance, standard deviation...and smoother stuff (@radial.module)

Comment: You folks are great :) Yes, I'm using java8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Java 8 you could use a method reference or lambda.

But I would simply change the way all of your data is stored in your student class. You could use an array, but I'd use an enum:

```
public enum Quiz {
  QUIZ_1,
  QUIZ_2,
  QUIZ_3,
  QUIZ_4,
  MID_TERM_1,
  MID_TERM_2,
  FINAL_TEST
}

public final class Student {
  private final EnumMap<Quiz, Double> grades
      = new EnumMap<>(Quiz.class);

  public void setGrade(Quiz quiz, double grade) {
    grades.put(quiz, grade);
  }

  public double getGrade(Quiz quiz) {
    Double grade = grades.get(quiz);
    if (grade == null) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException(
          "Student has no grade yet for quiz " + quiz);
    }
    return grade;
  }
}

static double computeAverage(List<Student> students, Quiz quiz) {
  double sum = 0;
  for (Student student : students) {
    sum += student.getGrade(quiz);
  }
  return sum / students.size();
}
```

**Update**: Since you mentioned that you are using Java 8, there's an even easier way, which makes use of some advanced Java 8 features.

Assuming your `Student` class has methods like `getQuiz1()`, `getQuiz2()`, etc., you could do:

```
List<Student> students = ...

DoubleSummaryStatistics stats = students.stream()
    .mapToDouble(Student::getQuiz1)
    .summaryStatistics();
double quiz1average = stats.getAverage();
double quiz1max = stats.getMax();
// etc.

// And likewise for quiz2:
DoubleSummaryStatistics stats = students.stream()
    .mapToDouble(Student::getQuiz2)
    .summaryStatistics();
```

Comment: This is my favorite answer for two reasons: 1. It's introducing me to a completely new concept that wasn't covered in my instruction (enum); 2. I can wrap my head around it easily thanks to your concise presentation. Thank you!

Comment: @radial.module: Thanks, I'm glad to help! I noticed that you said you're using Java 8, so if you want even more to wrap your head around, check out the advanced example I added.

Comment: Thanks Daniel! I dropped in the new example you provided and it works great. Now to dive in and start learning about streams and reduction :-)

Answer (score 1):

That is what structures like Arrays are good for.
Either extract the four quizes into an array or, if are allowed to, modify the  student class to represent them as an Array in the first place. So your code will look something like:

```
for every quiz
   for every student
       ...
```

Answer (score 1):

> Is the recommendation to extract the test scores into a temp array first and then just pass that to the average/min/max method?

Yes, you could do that. Or you could store them in arrays to begin with:

```
class Student {
    double[] scores = new double[7];
    static final int QUIZ1 = 0;
    static final int QUIZ2 = 1;
    ...

    static double average(Student[] students, int scoreIndex) {
        ...
        for(Student student : students) {
            sum += student.scores[scoreIndex];
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

(That might be unwieldy in practice, but probably uses concepts you are familiar with.)

Or you could use a [`Map`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/map.html):

```
class Student {
    Map<String, Double> scores = new HashMap<>();
    Student() {
        scores.put("quiz1", 0);
        scores.put("quiz2", 0);
        ...
    }

    static double average(Student[] students, String scoreKey) {
        ...
        for(Student student : students) {
            sum += student.scores.get(scoreKey);
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming quizzes are identifiable, let's say by a String name (or id, whatever), you should store their results for each student in a map:

```
private Map<String, Double> results = new HashMap<>();
```

Then add methods to student to get/set the results for a quiz:

```
public double getResult(String quiz) {
    if (results.containsKey(quiz))
        return results.get(quiz);
    return 0; // hasn't done quiz, so zero score
}

public void setResult(String quiz, double result) {
    results.put(quiz, result);
}
```

Then to calculate an average for a quiz for a some students:

```
public static double average(Collection<Student> students, String quiz) {
    double total = 0;
    for (Student student : students)
        total += student.getResult(quiz);
    return total / students.size();
}
```

Comment: I like this. My instructor only barely touched upon maps and I suspected they would have helped me solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to represent quiz1 quiz2 ect... as an array so something like this in your student object

```
class Student {
    double[] myQuizs = new double[4];

    public double[] getQuizScores(){
        return myQuizs;
    }
    public double getQuiz(double num){
        return myQuizs[n];
    }
}
```

then you could do this:

```
double quizTotal[] = {0,0,0,0};
double quizNAvg[] = {0,0,0,0};
double quizNMin[] = new double[4];
double quizNMax[] = new double[4];
for (int n = 0; n < 4; n++){
    for (int i = 0; i < studentsList.size(); i++) {
        quizTotal[n] += studentsList.get(i).getQuiz1();
        if (studentsList.get(i).getQuiz(n) > quizNMax[n])
            quizNMax[n] = studentsList.get(i).getQuiz(n); 

        if (studentsList.get(i).getQuiz(n) < quizNMin[n])
            quizNMin[n] = studentsList.get(i).getQuiz(n);     
     }
}
```

4 is the number of quizes i am assuming that there are. You could change that number.
You should modifie  quizTotal and quizNAvg so that they have the ammount of quizes as they do elements.